# Is it possible for parse cloud code to tell my app when to call a method?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

A user **calls a method** -> cloud code then sends out a alert **to other users using the app** -> a **method automatically calls** in the other users apps as a result of the cloud code alert.

I want to know if this is possible? And If there is anyway for me too achieve this?

Comment: It is possible to some extent. Flow should be: App calls cloud code function -> Cloud code function sends push notifications to other users -> Users with app in the foreground will receive the push and their application will do something. Users with the app closed will only receive the push, but won't do anything until the app is opened

Comment: Why does the method need to have a specific name?  Why can't it be `calledFromCloud:` or something?